# Unable to get subdomain to connect to MariaDB

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, mysql, database, nginx-reverse-proxy

So far I can reach the DB from the main domain lets say example.com but connection from the subdomain lets say portal.example.com, don't work. I am currently running Nginx & Varnish & Apache on CWP7PRO. I have basic user data on the database and when i try to login using <form id="login action="login.php" method="post">, from the main domain I can, but from the subdomain I get an "Access Denied" error

Comment: Welcome and thank you for posting. Getting good answers requires a clear and useful question which is [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) , [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and contains sufficient details (error messages, configuration details etc.)  to provide you with a good solution. - Please improve your question to address those points or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved and/or having your question closed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it was a permissions issue. Permission for my functions files were all set to 640 meaning that the owner has read and write permissions, the group has read permissions, and all other user have no rights to the file.. I had to change them to 644, giving read rights to other users